# Is there anyway to get my droid Maxx to recognize my external hard drive that is NTFS not fat 32

Tags: motorola-droid

I have done a lot of research on this and it would seem like in this day in age this would not be very hard to figure out

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Paragon? [Paragon Mounter - Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.paragon.mounter&hl=en)

Referenced from here: [NTFS With & Without Root](http://techpp.com/2015/06/25/how-to-enable-ntfs-support-on-android-with-without-root/)

Comment: It says I have to be rooted and so far I have not found anyway to root 4.4.4 KitKat

Comment: Oh boy. Looks like yours is a challenge to root, I saw this [root video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyDnN3_hAmA) and I can see your situation. Got any other Androids you can use? Some of us Android junkies have a drawer-full, ha.